# Bridging hardware interfaces in KVM on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Hi I am trying to bridge a USB C hub network interface from my host machine directly into a VM so I can run DHCPD and communicate both ways between the VM and the hardware interface. Which is the following in my host on bridge:

[image: hardware link setting]

What I expect KVM to do here is link the virtual interface from my container through. I have the following container working on my host but not in the KVM guest. The KVM guest is not giving out any leases but does run the container

[image: Container in KVM]

Compared to where it does work on the host without bridiging of course.

[image: On Host]

I may be missing a step but I don't get which step(s)?

Comment: try [the Ubuntu Serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-libvirt),  - scroll down to "Device Passthrough / Hotplug", which is new material added for 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advantageously found it through the mac address in my netplan file

```
ip a | grep 00:FF
```

This method didn't work with net-tools/if config, no clear reason why.
The config issue was in netpan, I made a mistake that in my syntax. My qemu config was fine.